# why is playback really slow, but scrubbing really fast?

Tags: 3d-view

why is playback really slow, but scrubbing really fast?  This is in a scene with nothing but a single character and armature.

i'm getting 4 fps when using alt a or pressing play, but when I scrub by hand,  everything updates just as fast as I scrub up to around 80fps (for a guess).

Answer (score 1):

When you manually scrub you´re forcing the playback to update on current frame. But when playback is set to play by default it will calculate vertices, deformations (armature) and other effects.
If you´re on 2.79 blender, make an OGL capture from the Render menu or by pressing this icon:[image]

That will render a capture sequence to the OUTPUT directory you´ve set your files to OUTPUT from on your properties->scene->render output on your blender file (panels to your right side of the screen).

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Any way around it without running a capture sequence?  The odd thing is that any changes I make to the animation are reflected when scrubbing, so it must be updating something when scrubbing?